# How to compensate students who face technical issues in online exams

Tags: university, exams, online-learning

I am teaching a college level course, and a few students had technical issues during exam 1 (held online) and where not able to complete various parts of the exam.  One option that I could think of is to use their grade from a future exam (also held online) as their exam 1 grade. Designing another complete exam 1 is not an option in our case.

But I am wondering if there are better alternatives.... could you share your experiences regarding dealing with such issues?

Comment: Arbitrarily choosing another assignment to count for double credit doesn't seem like a great choice - it can give an advantage/disadvantage if that other assignment is any easier/harder than the one that was missed. Simply not including Exam 1 in the scoring for students that missed it is probably more fair.

Comment: Is this a course where grades must be on a curve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I have been doing this year, depending on the class, is to either allow the students who have technical problems to take a makeup exam in another day on the part they couldn't complete, or to compensate with an additional question at the oral exam.

From your question, I'd either integrate the missing parts with an oral discussion, if oral exams are acceptable in your country or university, or with a written test with a few questions around the missing parts without redesigning the whole exam though.

Answer (score 18):

I guess this answer won't be popular, but my strong suggestion is that you rethink student evaluation from the start. Exams aren't the only way that you can assess student learning and they are a poor way, in any case, to assess real competence in a field like CS. Add in all of the ways to creatively cheat on online exams and it quickly becomes a near impossible task to validate results.

Some ideas, but I don't have a comprehensive list:

Assess in smaller units more frequently so that "high risk" isn't a factor.

Make the grading scheme somewhat forgiving, so that a few bad answers don't have a large effect on grades.

Take "time to finish" out of the equation as much as possible to account for technical glitches.

Lessen the importance of "question - answer" grading in favor of things like projects that require deeper and more comprehensive knowledge.

Use questions that don't have trivial answers than can be quickly looked up. Likewise don't reuse questions that might have archived answers.

Lessen the importance of "individual work" at least somewhat. Effective teamwork is an important skill in many fields, including CS.

For some students it may be necessary to provide a communication channel to clear up misunderstandings. But make it global. Everyone should see every question and its answer.

For some student issues it may be necessary to talk to professionals skilled in the various communication difficulties that arise (dyslexia...).

Comment: "competence in a field like CS" OP doesn't specify a field.

Comment: @Roland, their profile suggested that this is their field. But it applies to many fields: Philosophy, say.

Comment: All good suggestions but not always practical.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, certainly impractical if you blow them off. Nothing works until you make it work.

Comment: I already do a lot of the stuff you suggest but - for instance - it’s not terribly practical to have projects in a class of 75 students.  I have colleagues who chose to go the essay route, but reading 100 5-page essays is overwhelming, and while it cuts down on copying it doesn’t cut down on plagiarism: students just cut-and-paste from the web...

Comment: @ZeroTheHero "it’s not terribly practical to have projects in a class of 75 students" My university regularly does projects in classes composed of hundreds of students. My understanding is that one of the tricks to making it work is to have all the students enroll into tutorials of 20-30 students each, and then getting the tutors do the marking. Additionally, if you make the projects group projects with teams of 5, then 75 students becomes 15 teams, which is a lot easier to mark.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero "I have colleagues who chose to go the essay route, but reading 100 5-page essays is overwhelming," Well, that's one reason why you might consider assigning them more practical projects instead. In CS, you might assign them coding assignments, in Engineering you might have them design CAD files for a device, in Science they might need to solve a particular problem using the scientific principles they've studied, etc.

Comment: @nick012000 Don’t get me wrong: one can mitigate some of the effects.  I do (team) projects as well in smaller classes where each team has a different project, but in a larger setting with  10 teams working on solutions to the restricted 3-body problem you displace the problem to one of plagiarism.  My point is: in larger settings and in more junior classes, there’s a trade-off not there in smaller classes.  Exams remain the compromise solutions for larger classes, and presumably carefully designed final exams - *e.g* with quasi-randomized questions -  will mitigate some issues.

Comment: @nick012000 For Freshmen CS, doing scientific work with papers is too much, coding (projects) should IMHO only be a small part of CS.  For us it's mostly down to small proofs and checking whether the students understood a set of basic concepts.

Comment: @ljrk "coding (projects) should IMHO only be a small part of CS." That's how you get university graduates that don't know how to code.

Comment: @nick012000 Which is fine by me.  They're academics/scientists, not coders.  Noone is asking a medical researcher to be able to perform surgeries either, or a theoretical physicist to be good at wiring your home.

Comment: @ljrk, actually, the OP does seem to be in CS/SE from the profile. So, coding is a necessary skill, needed at a pretty high level for all the other things.

Comment: @ljrk If a student is getting an undergraduate computer science degree, they're training to become software engineers and the degree should be focused to provide them with the skills and qualifications to get a job in industry; undergraduate degrees in general should be focused on giving students the skills needed to get jobs in their fields upon graduating. They're not academics or scientists, and they're not training to become academics or scientists until they start a research degree like a PhD.

Comment: @nick012000 I find that absurd, being academic is not a "more trained" engineer, that is, you shouldn't first need to become an engineer to become an academic. These are simply different branches of equally worth paths to go along. That's why there's Computer *Science*, Computer *Engineering* and Information Technology, or B.Sc., B.Eng. and B.A. degrees. It doesn't make sense to see an academic as a more highly qualified version of an engineer. (but that's already rather offtopic here, I just wanted to note that programming tasks are not always the right thing to do)

Comment: @ljrk "That's why there's Computer Science, Computer Engineering and Information Technology, or B.Sc., B.Eng. and B.A. degrees." I don't see the difference between these that you're emphasizing; they're basically just different names for the same thing, unless "computer engineering" is supposed to be an actual Engineering degree about designing physical computer components, rather than an IT degree about programming them.

Comment: @nick012000 One is academic, with the goal of research, IT gives you almost craftsman like skills, and engineers are the middle ground, system design etc.  The IT student needs to be skillful programmer commonly used languages, while the academic focuses on more general concepts.  These are *different branches*, just like a MD is different from a medical researcher, and shares only basic skills. The latter aren't just "better qualified" MDs, they pursue a different degree. It's simply absurd, to think of an academic CS as someone who continued after becoming an engineer. But this is all OT.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree with many of the points you raised. Unfortunately sometimes we need to follow specific rules of a college.

Comment: @nick012000 If you see "Computer Science, Computer Engineering and Information Technology" as all roughly synonymous, then I suggest you re-examine these fields.  They loosely overlap, but... that's it.  Software Engineering is also a degree students can pursue.  Computer Science is the most mathematical of these fields.  The fact that more universities traditionally offer CS than CE, SE, or IT is a result of the history of these fields and how they developed, and that situation is slowly changing.  You couldn't get a degree in SE 30 years ago at all.

Comment: @BenI. Not "roughly synonymous", entirely synonymous. Literally just different names for the exact same thing: three or four years spent learning how to code computer programs (again, unless "computer engineering" is about designing hardware rather than software - "software engineering" is also entirely synonymous with the other three).

Comment: @nick012000 I don't know what to say to that. There's no benefit to conflating these fields. Programmers get computers to do things. Computer Science has been about the underlying science and maths of automatic computation since the coin was termed.  You need almost no understanding of the underlying mathematics to do the former, and virtually no ability as a programmer to do the latter. Plenty of middle school kids can create phone apps but can't talk about NP-hard, and I'd venture that most mathematicians who expand complexity theory can't code up a simple web app with a linked database.

Comment: @BenI., note that some universities do, actually, use different terms for the same thing. Some "Software Engineering" programs are really CS, even though the meaning is quite different. Some of this is just historical accident. But I agree, that at base, the fields themselves are very distinct.

Comment: @BenI. The purpose of a university is to teach students the skills they need to find work after they graduate; that's why students go to university. Do you think employers care about NP Hard? No, they care about coders who can produce good code - so that's what the university should care about teaching.

Comment: @nick012000, that is a very limited view of the mission of a university. The CS degree is not a coding school.

Comment: @nick012000 I don't think I could disagree more strongly.  You're not the first, nor will you be the last, to say that about the purpose of education, but I find that view to border on morally repugnant. I don't think we're going to reach any agreement here if you begin from that premise, so at this point I'm just going to wish you the best of luck in your future endeavors, and a good and meaningful life.

Comment: @BenI. And I find failing to equip students for their future careers equally morally repugnant.

Answer (score 5):

My philosophy is that the vote is my best statistical estimate of the student's preparation on the whole of the course's contents, based on what I can evaluate during the exam. If I taught 30 topics during the course and I ask 3 of them during the exam, then I can assume their answers reflect their preparation also on the other 27 topics. There is an error bar, of course, but that's unavoidable, given the limited time I can put in for each student.

So, if you have more tests, you are good; just skip Exam 1 (EDIT: I mean, ignore it just for the students that could not complete it; students who have a full set of grades should still be evaluated on all of them) and renormalize the outcomes of the further exams. The error bars will be larger, but this is unavoidable.

Comment: By this logic, there's no point in having two exams at all--just ask one question at the end of the term and score everyone pass/fail! Less pithy: This response ignores the time dependency between scores and the possibility that one exam is harder than the other, and it doesn't provide students with a uniform incentive to try to do better on the second exam or learn from their mistakes on the first.

Comment: @Max The point of having two exams is that error bars are shorter. Choosing how many questions to ask and how many exams to make is always a tradeoff between effort and grading accuracy. Exam difficulty, of course, should be included in my grade estimation. I am not sure I follow you on the incentive thing. Why is it important that they have a uniform incentive? How can I even give the same incentive to an A+ student and an F student? How is this relevant in the context of this question (some students skipped one exam for technical reasons)?

Comment: If you throw out exam 1 for the students who missed it and leave it in for the students who didn't, then there is greater variance in the scores of the latter group, and thus their final grades offer less indication of their knowledge of the subject than the other students'. If you throw out exam 1 for everyone, then a student who does worse on exam 2 can justifiably claim they weren't graded according to this syllabus.

Comment: Not to mention that if you show the students that having technical issues negates the score entirely, then the dominant strategy for a student who did well on exam 1 is to claim to encounter technical issues on exam 2. And you probably *do not* want to be in the position of having to judge subjectively which claims of technical issues are valid or not.

Comment: @Max The last argument is a good point. I was assuming that we know exactly what happened in these technical issues, but this may not be true. (Again, if you see the exams as a statistical test, this makes sense: the fact that the students affected by the problems are a random sample independent from their score is a hidden assumption).

Comment: "Variance" is a synonym of "error bars", essentially, so we are saying the same thing. Given the technical issues, I do not feel compelled to follow the syllabus, since those rules have already been broken for external circumstances and I don't think they can be recovered since OP states that a makeup exam is not possible.

Comment: What I'm saying is that if the situation necessitates violating the grading policy on the syllabus, you should take care to ensure that it gives students *the same grade or better* as they would have had according to the original policy (to the extent possible). Otherwise you are just asking for grade disputes. If you got an A on exam 1, a B- on exam 2, and a B- in the class, it would be justifiable to be upset, no?

Comment: I am advocating skipping exam 1 just for the students that don't have a valid grade on it; maybe this was not clear from my answer so I'll edit it.

Comment: I agree that that policy is marginally better, but it still has the unequal variances problem. An A average over two exams is a stronger indication of understanding than an A average over one exam, but this distinction won't be reflected on students' transcripts. And you have to take care to ensure that if exam 2 is harder/easier than exam 1, then the students who only took exam 2 don't get unfairly penalized/rewarded.

Comment: @Max Unequal variances are not a dealbreaker under my philosophy. Anyhow, every solution to this problem is going to increase variances (unequally) *or* increase effort; if you have a different tradeoff to suggest, feel free to add your answer.

Comment: "Unequal variances are not a dealbreaker"
So you are fine with someone receiving a mark of 5+-0.01, and another student receiving a mark of 4.5+-0.75 ?



Please put this at the header of the answer. It makes clear that you are not interested in giving equal examination.

Comment: @EarlGrey It is already written in my answer: "The error bars will be larger, but this is unavoidable". I don't think it belongs in the header.

Comment: Fair marking requires by definition a common error bar. Ignoring that, you are implicitly saying that you are giving markings for the same course, for the same students, with two different methods.
This is not fair, by definition.

I still think your answer is helpful, it helps focusing on the correct definition of mark/grades, thanks!

Comment: @EarlGrey There are unequal conditions here: some students completed an exam, some couldn't due to technical issues, and the exam cannot be repeated due to practical constraints. Discussing 'fairness' for spherical students in a vacuum won't help us here.

Comment: Your claim about spherical student it's absurd, especially coming from someone in STEM.
Here we have real students, that deserve fair grading. Technical issues may hamper the variance (error bar, if you like) on their marks. You propose a solution based on the assumption that variance in marking is not important (talking about spherical students...) which is very helpful, in remarking that variance is important in markings.

Answer (score 3):

Grade the complete exams, for everyone, then remove all the "various parts of the exam" that could not be completed for everyone, give marks again, pick the higher mark for each student.

It's the only fair thing you can do, given the conditions.